# The application could not be installed. Installation failed due to: 'Invalid File: <path>.apk

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to run the app on Note8 device using Android Studio and facing this issue after updating the variant output Directory path inside app/build.gradle file. There are lot of similar kind of issues I have seen, but none of their solutions are working for me.

I am on Android studio 3.6.+ and note 8 device, Also the funny things is path it's showing doesn't exist currently, it is the old path for variant.output in my app/build.gradle file.

changes after which the error started:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def outputDir = new File("${project.buildDir.absolutePath}/outputs/apk")
        def outputFileName = "DEMO-${variant.flavorName}-Build-${versionName}.apk"
        variant.packageApplicationProvider.get().outputDirectory = new File("$outputDir")
        output.outputFileName = outputFileName
    }
}
```

before changes: outputDir is the  where it's showing the file is missing error.

```
def outputDir = new File("${project.buildDir.absolutePath}/outputs/apk/${variant.flavorName}/${variant.buildType.name}")
def outputFileName = "DEMO-${variant.flavorName}-${variant.buildType.name}-${versionName}.apk"
```

Things I have tried so far:
I have tried clean and rebuild project, I have tried invalid cache and restart, I have tried deleting .idea, cache and .build directories, Also I have no application with the same package name already installed in my device.

Could some one suggest the possible cause and how to resolve it?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

if cleaning, rebuilding and invalidating cache and deleting build folder inside app directory don't work

try this one

**File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run > uncheck 'Enable Instant Run to hot swap code'**

Comment: Thanks for answering but it not useful as Android Studio 3.6 does not have instant run feature. They removed the option in new Android studio.

Comment: Ok sorry for that,  have you tried running it on different devices? Emulator? Do you have multi user on your phone?

Comment: Nop. Only one user profile on my phone. I didn't try running it on different device. But my doubt is; the invalid path it is showing is belongs to my build directory inside project folder, this used to be the path for build output in my app/build.gradle. I have updated the question have a look.

Comment: are you using the latest Gradle build ?

Comment: do you mean gradle tool version then yes I am on 3.6.4

Comment: Maybe try 4.1.0?

Answer (score 0):

For those who might still be having this problem, You can cleaning, rebuilding and invalidating caches does not work, couple of things to try,

1. Upgrade Your gradle build version to the latest version.
2. If your code is kolin, check Kotlin version used for building with Gradle is same from the one bundled into the IDE plugin. Upgrade to that bundled into the IDE

Then sync, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may try it:

**File >> Invalidate Caches** and check two options

- Clear file system cache and Local History
- Clear VCS Log caches and indexes

Then,

**Build >> Clean project**
**Build >> Rebuild project**

Now **Run** you code.